# How to access one checkbox in QML from .cpp in QT?

Tags: c++, qt, checkbox, qt-quick

Recently, I got a small problem, which is accessing the checkbox in qml from cpp in QT. So the problem is quite simple: I have a `main.qml` file, which has a checkbox, I want to update the "`checked`" property to true or false based on the configuration that I saved in QSettings when I launch the application. Currently, I have successfully load the setting from QSettings in cpp file when application startup. Then how to modify the "`checked`" property in this cpp file?

I tried this :http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html and used the `findChild` function but it does not work.

1), I put `import <QtQuick>` in cpp file but i got error as `QtQuick file can't be found`.

2), I changed to "`import <QtQuick/QQuickView>`". Solved 1) but got new error for this line `QObject* object = view.rootObject();`:

```
cannot initialize a variable of type 'QObject *' with an rvalue of type 'QQuickItem *`
```

3), I changed `QObject* object = view.rootObject();` this line to `QQuickItem* object = view.rootObject();` and used `QObject* acbox = object->findChild<QObject* >("acbox");` after that. (acbox is the objectName of that checkbox) Solved 2) but got new error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "QQuickView::setSource(QUrl const&)", referenced from:
      ndn::TrayMenu::TrayMenu(QQmlContext*, ndn::Face&) in tray-menu.cpp.1.o
  "QQuickView::QQuickView(QWindow*)", referenced from:
      ndn::TrayMenu::TrayMenu(QQmlContext*, ndn::Face&) in tray-menu.cpp.1.o
  "QQuickView::~QQuickView()", referenced from:
      ndn::TrayMenu::TrayMenu(QQmlContext*, ndn::Face&) in tray-menu.cpp.1.o
  "QQuickView::rootObject() const", referenced from:
      ndn::TrayMenu::TrayMenu(QQmlContext*, ndn::Face&) in tray-menu.cpp.1.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Anyone has any suggestion? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use setproperty in cpp to set a property in qml and then bind that to the checked status in qml file check the following code

C++ part:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine; 
    QQmlComponent component(&engine, QUrl("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject *object = component.create();
    object->setProperty("checkstatus", false);
    return app.exec();
}
```

QML part:

```
Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    property bool checkstatus


    CheckBox {
        id:checkbox
        text: qsTr("checkbox1")
        checked: checkstatus
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the example in your ref QT page?  the below example connect the qml signal to the C++ class's slot, but I think it should be possible to do inverse, that: you connect your C++'s variable's signal who wants the checkbox update. then it connects to the QML's slot that do the update of checkbox.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQuickView view(QUrl::fromLocalFile("MyItem.qml"));
    QObject *item = view.rootObject();

    MyClass myClass;
    QObject::connect(item, SIGNAL(qmlSignal(QString)),
                     &myClass, SLOT(cppSlot(QString)));

    view.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```